# Password does not meet the password policy requirements

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, password-policy

I keep getting the "Password does not meet the password policy requirements" message when trying to reset existing user passwords / create passwords for new users.

I am logged into a Windows Server 2016 server as a domain administrator.

[image: Cannot complete the password change]

I disabled the password complexity requirements (I also tried Not Defined) on the Default Domain Policy GPO. Ran gpupdate /force.

[image: Group Policy Management Editor]

Comment: Check the Default Domain Controller GPO as well. In fact, on a DC, run RSOP or some other tool to ensure that this setting isn't being defined in any GPO that applies to the domain controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just checked the Default Domain Controller GPO - all policies are set to Not Defined. I also tried setting the complexity requirements policy to Disabled.

Comment: Issue resolved - the server we inherited has some settings that prevent long passwords.

Comment: Then that would be worth documenting the actual settings you found, and posting them here as the answer. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, you were able the find the answer and someone else might encounter the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find the setting. The server has since been decommissioned.

Answer (score 0):

check that any policy applied to your active directory domain controller by
`gpresult -h c:\result.html` command. if your disabling gpo not applied, first open local security policy on your server and disable password complexity then `gpupdate /force`. then check if you can change password now or not.